# Cant connect to hive server through beeline

Tags: hive, beeline

I started hiveserver2. I am trying to connect to the server through beeline with

```
beeline> !connect jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/default
```

Then I give a blank username and password and get this error:

```
 castor is not allowed to impersonate anonymous
```

Please can someone help me connect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set proxyuser [property](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/Superusers.html)for impersonating at  core-site.xml

ie 
    hadoop.proxyuser.hive.groups=*

```
hadoop.proxyuser.hive.hosts=*
```

you can find more logs on oozie launcher logs will help you debugging more.